# Count lines in the file Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to count how many lines of data there are in my file, and I am using this piece of code to do it :

```
data = try String(contentsOfFile: localFilePath as String,
                          encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
let textArr = data.componentsSeparatedByString("\r")
        let myCount = textArr.count
        print(myCount)
```

However no matter how many lines of text there are in my file it always seems to print `1`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try to seperate the data with "\n"?

Comment: You should use NSUTF8StringEncodig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the terminator to "\n".

It is possible your file has Unix-like line endings. Meaning lines will be terminated with \n.

Unix-like systems (such as OS X and iOS) typically terminate lines with \n.
Windows terminates lines with \r\n.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations

Answer (score 6):

We could guess whether the lines are split by `'\r'`, `'\n'`, or whatever else, or we could wisely use the new line character set:

```
let newLineSet = NSCharacterSet().newLineCharacterSet()
let textArr = data.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(newLineSet)
```